# Exception trying to run ASP.NET 5 Docker container

Tags: asp.net, linux, docker, nuget, asp.net-core

Trying to create my Docker container. Image builds without issue but then when I try and run:

```
docker run -t -d --name website website
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'Asp.Net,Version=v5.0':
   app 1.0.0
   Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces 1.0.0-beta2

Searched Locations:
  /{name}/project.json
  /root/.kpm/packages/{name}/{version}/{name}.nuspec
  /usr/lib/mono/4.5/{name}.dll
  /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/{name}.dll

Try running 'kpm restore'.

  at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost.GetEntryPoint (System.String applicationName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Looks like a missing reference but that is definitely referenced in project.json as I'm including Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.

It suggests running kpm restore but I can't do this because container isn't running.

Anyone seen anything similar before?

**UPDATE #1**

OK so if I add an explicit reference to Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces that resolves but I'm still left with app 1.0.0 which I have no idea about

**UPDATE #2**

Here's my project.json:

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "dependencies": {
        "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0.0-beta1",
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-22231"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
        "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnetcore50": {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe not applicable for everyone, but for our final vNext images, we copy in the dependencies manually. Makes containers start _much_ faster and eliminates errors like the one you saw. Otherwise, maybe make a new image based on the vNext one and add a "RUN kpm restore"?

Comment: Can you please post the `project.json` file?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci have added project.json thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are trying to run on CoreCLR (`aspnetcore50`).

Since you are running on Linux/Mono, you should target DesktopCLR (`aspnet50`) instead.

Comment: I think you're right Victor. I added in the DesktopCLR and restore was successful. So am I right that CoreCLR is only for cloud apps or will it be applicable for Linux in future? Been trying to find good docs but no luck so far :(

Comment: Sweet, didn't realize what I was doing wrong. I noticed some activity on the dnx repo that suggested coreclr runs on Linux now; is that already in beta6?